# Fluent NHibernate mappings for Domain objects with interface typed reference (in a S#arp arch app)

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I'm trying to code my domain to interfaces types rather than concrete types.

Skeleton examples of two domain objects are:

```
public class Supplier : ISupplier
{
   public virtual IContract Contract {get; set;}
}

public class Contract : IContract
{
   public virtual List<ISuppliers> Suppliers {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way to Fluently map my supplier so that it will cast to concrete domain objects for data access?

I currently get the error

NHibernate.MappingException: An association from the table Supplier refers to an unmapped class: IContract

With the following supplierMap

```
References(x => x.Contract).Column("ContractId")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
References<Contract>(x => x.Contract).Column("ContractId");
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672032/fluent-nhibernate-working-with-interfaces/2114087#2114087).

Comment: Much Obliged Chum - Works a treat. My Google foo deserted me when I posted!