# NHibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate persister: ABC.Interfaces.Entities.IUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

I'm getting this error:

NHibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate persister: ABC.Interfaces.Entities.IUser

Does this mean the mapping file (I'm using fluent) isn't being found for some reason?

In my nhibernate.data project I have the below definition:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<IUser>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Username);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        Map(x => x.Firstname);
        Map(x => x.Lastname);

        Map(x => x.CreatedDate);
        Map(x => x.UpdatedDate);
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Or does it have to do with castle windsor not picking up the implementation?

I have:

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IUser>().ImplementedBy<User>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672032/fluent-nhibernate-working-with-interfaces/683364#683364). It seems that the problem may be in the mapping of IUser in NH