# How to use an Interface as part of a CompositeID in fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, composite-id

I'm having trouble figuring out how to map an interface while using a composite key.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
interface Ifoo
{
  int someInt {get;}
  int id {get;}
}

class bar1: Ifoo
{
  int someInt {get; protected internal set;}
  int id {get; protected internal set;}
}

class bar2: Ifoo
{
  int someInt {get; protected internal set;}
  int id {get; protected internal set;}
}

class someOtherClass
{
  Ifoo myFoo {get; protected internal set;}
  int id {get; protected internal set;}
}

public class someOtherClassMap: ClassMap<someOtherClass>
{
  CompositeId()
    .KeyReference(x => x.myFoo, "fooID")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.id, "id");

  References(x => x.myFoo)
    .Class(typeof (foo1))
    .Class(typeof (foo2))
    .Column("fooID")
    .Not.Insert()
    .Not.Update();
}
```

The References works without issue, but I can't get the KeyReference to work, and there doesn't seem to be any ".Class" I can use like I can with References.

I read:

[Fluent NHibernate, working with interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672032/fluent-nhibernate-working-with-interfaces)

[Programming to interfaces while mapping with Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845536/programming-to-interfaces-while-mapping-with-fluent-nhibernate)

and that let me fix the References issue, but I haven't found a work around for the KeyReference. Is there something obvious I'm missing, cause I've been googling around for awhile, and so far haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

this maybe works

```
.KeyReference(x => x.myFoo, attr => attr.Column("fooID").EntityName("bar1"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using an older version of fluent, I don't have any functions that match that signature.

Comment: then you have to do reflection or extend your own version of FNH. I can post the code for reflection if needed.